# Django model layer for HBase support

Tags: python, database, django, hbase

I am looking for HBase backend support for Django.

Does anyone know if something like that exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't exist at the minute have a look at this [recent discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/9827f3758d7f7776). It is a suggested Hbase support GSoC project, but is turned down on the basis that mongoDB project was worked on last year and has not yet been added to trunk. Hbase baackend works quite differently from Django's ORM design, in short support isn't there at the minute, and any support for non-relational db's is unlikely to hit the core any time soon.

Comment: Any updates on this ? Can I use HBase with Django now ?